# How can I get the previous row in gridview rowdatabound?

Tags: asp.net, aspxgridview, rowdatabound

I would like to check the previous row data if it is equal to `--`,
if it is not equal to `--` then I would enable button in the next row

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
       if (DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "time_start").ToString() == "--")
       {
            Button btn = ((Button)e.Row.FindControl("Edit_Button"));
            btn.Enabled = false;
       }   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also do it like this using `GridView1.Rows[e.Row.RowIndex - 1]`.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        GridViewRow prevrow = GridView1.Rows[e.Row.RowIndex - 1];
        if( prevrow.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            // Your code for manipulating prevrow
        }
        if (DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "time_start").ToString() == "--")
        {
            Button btn = ((Button)e.Row.FindControl("Edit_Button"));
            btn.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is:

- Create a field `previousRow` in your class, of type `GridViewRow`.
- Initialize this field to null in the a `GridView.DataBinding` event handler.  This event is fired when databinding starts, before any of the RowDataBound events fires.
- In your `GridView.RowDataBound` event handler, do your processing (including comparing with `previousRow`), then set `previousRow = e.Row`.