# GridView - get value of a cell in a certain column of each row, before rendered?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a gridview which is populated with data. I would like to evaluate each row in the gridview before it is presented to see if the row is valid to display. In the first column of a row I want to pass that through a function which will return a boolean result

In Pseudo code:

```
FOR Each row in GridView
IF functionCheckRow(GridView.Rows(i).Cells(0).Text) = False Then
    GridView.Rows(i).Visible = False
End IF
Next
```

Using ASP/VB.Net I so far have this:

```
Private Sub GridView_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles  GridView_RowDataBound.RowDataBound

    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then    'Not the header row?
        Dim index As Integer = e.Row.RowIndex
        Dim currentRow As GridViewRow =  GridView_RowDataBound.Rows(index)


        Dim currentItem = currentRow.Cells(index).Text
        If functionCheckPerms(currentItem ) <> "" Then
            e.Row.Visible = False
        End If
        currentItem = ""
    End If
```

However, try as I might I can't seem to get the index of the current row. On this line:

```
Dim currentRow As GridViewRow =  GridView_RowDataBound.Rows(index)
```

I get: "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index" with the value set to 0. Am I going about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

This could be a duplicate of 
[How can I get the previous row in gridview rowdatabound?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26417949/how-can-i-get-the-previous-row-in-gridview-rowdatabound)

Basically, you need to subtract 1 from the row-index.

```
Dim index as Integer = e.Row.RowIndex - 1
```